# System.InvalidOperationException: A DbContext instance cannot be used inside OnConfiguring since it is still being configured at this point

Tags: .net-core, async-await, entity-framework-core, dbcontext, invalidoperationexception

I am encountering below error while doing load testing in my applicaiton. This error does not appear while doing load testing from postman. Can anyone help me out with this. I don't know what is getting wrong here.

> An attempt was made to use the context while it is being configured. A DbContext instance cannot be used inside OnConfiguring since it is still being configured at this point. This can happen if a second operation is started on this context before a previous operation completed. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.

```
   // Service regisered in Startup.cs
   services.AddTransient<IExceptionHandlerService, ExceptionHandlerService>();
    
   // Calling the below method like this
   return exceptionHandler.LogRequestAsync(log);
    
   // LogRequestAsync method inside ExceptionHandlerService class is 
   // throwing this error

   public class ExceptionHandlerService : IExceptionHandlerService
   {

    private ConnectionStrings _connectionStrings;
    private myapp_myappContext dbContext;

    public ExceptionHandlerService(IOptions<ConnectionStrings> connectionStrings)
    {
        _connectionStrings = connectionStrings.Value;
        dbContext = new myapp_myappContext(_connectionStrings);
    }

    // This method is throwing error. This method was not async earlier. 
    // I made this async due to the above error but still, 
    // the result is the same.
    public async Task<int> LogRequestAsync(RequestLogDto model)
    {
        try
        {
            var log = new MyappRequestlog()
            {
                Ipaddress = model.Ipaddress,
                UserId = model.UserId,
                Url = model.Url,
                MethodType = model.MethodType,
                Urlreferrer = model.Urlreferrer,
                Browser = model.Browser,
                Device = model.Device,
                RequestBody = model.RequestBody,
                Response = model.Response,
                ExceptionMessage = model.ExceptionMessage,
                StackTrace = model.StackTrace,
                CreatedDate = DateTime.Now
            };
            dbContext = new myapp_myappContext(_connectionStrings);
            await dbContext.MyappRequestlog.AddAsync(log);
            await dbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            return log.LogId;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string strFilePath = ApplicationVariables.ErrorFilePath;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(strFilePath))
            {
                File.AppendAllLines(strFilePath, new[] { $"{ex}. Error generate datetime : {DateTime.Now}" });
            }
            return 0;
        }
    }

    public virtual DbSet<MyappExternalcalllog> MyappExternalcalllog { get; set; }

    // This is OnConfiguringmethod which the error is indicating
    protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
    {
        if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
        {
            optionsBuilder.UseMySql(_connectionStrings.DefaultConnection);
        }
    }


    // This method is saving data in database
    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
      modelBuilder.Entity<MyappRequestlog>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasKey(e => e.LogId);

            entity.ToTable("myapp_requestlog");

            entity.Property(e => e.LogId).HasColumnType("int(11)");

            entity.Property(e => e.Browser).HasColumnType("varchar(1000)");

            entity.Property(e => e.CreatedDate).HasColumnType("datetime");

            entity.Property(e => e.Device).HasColumnType("varchar(15)");

            entity.Property(e => e.ExceptionMessage).HasColumnType("text");

            entity.Property(e => e.Ipaddress)
                .HasColumnName("IPAddress")
                .HasColumnType("varchar(25)");

            entity.Property(e => e.MethodType).HasColumnType("varchar(9)");

            entity.Property(e => e.RequestBody).HasColumnType("text");

            entity.Property(e => e.Response).HasColumnType("text");

            entity.Property(e => e.StackTrace).HasColumnType("text");

            entity.Property(e => e.Url)
                .HasColumnName("URL")
                .HasColumnType("text");

            entity.Property(e => e.Urlreferrer)
                .HasColumnName("URLReferrer")
                .HasColumnType("text");

            entity.Property(e => e.UserId).HasColumnType("varchar(38)");
        });
     }
```

// Following is the stack trace for this error

```
System.InvalidOperationException: An attempt was made to use the context while it is being configured. A DbContext instance cannot be used inside OnConfiguring since it is still being configured at this point. This can happen if a second operation is started on this context before a previous operation completed. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.EntryWithoutDetectChanges[TEntity](TEntity entity)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SetEntityState[TEntity](TEntity entity, EntityState entityState)
   at MyApp.LoggerService.ExceptionHandlerService.LogRequest(RequestLogDto model) in D:\My API and Application TFS\My API\WebAPICore\MyAPI_V2\MyApp.LoggerService\ExceptionHandlerService.cs:line 47. Error generate datetime : 07/07/2020 10:41:26
System.InvalidOperationException: An attempt was made to use the context while it is being configured. A DbContext instance cannot be used inside OnConfiguring since it is still being configured at this point. This can happen if a second operation is started on this context before a previous operation completed. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_InternalServiceProvider()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.get_DbContextDependencies()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.EntryWithoutDetectChanges[TEntity](TEntity entity)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SetEntityState[TEntity](TEntity entity, EntityState entityState)
   at MyApp.LoggerService.ExceptionHandlerService.LogRequest(RequestLogDto model) in D:\My API and Application TFS\My API\WebAPICore\MyAPI_V2\MyApp.LoggerService\ExceptionHandlerService.cs:line 47. Error generate datetime : 07/07/2020 10:41:26
System.InvalidOperationException: A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ConcurrencyDetector.EnterCriticalSection()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(IReadOnlyList`1 entriesToSave)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
at MyApp.LoggerService.ExceptionHandlerService.LogRequest(RequestLogDto model) in D:\My API and Application TFS\My API\WebAPICore\MyAPI_V2\MyApp.LoggerService\ExceptionHandlerService.cs:line 47. Error generate datetime : 07/07/2020 10:41:27
System.InvalidOperationException: A second operation started on this context before a previous operation completed. Any instance members are not guaranteed to be thread safe.
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Internal.ConcurrencyDetector.EnterCriticalSection()
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(IReadOnlyList`1 entriesToSave)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.Internal.StateManager.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbContext.SaveChanges(Boolean acceptAllChangesOnSuccess)
   at MyApp.LoggerService.ExceptionHandlerService.LogRequest(RequestLogDto model) in D:\My API and Application TFS\My API\WebAPICore\MyAPI_V2\MyApp.LoggerService\ExceptionHandlerService.cs:line 47. Error generate datetime : 07/07/2020 10:41:27
```

Comment: Can you share the stack trace of the exception?

Comment: @PauloMorgado Hi Paulo. Thanks!! for looking into this issue. Stack trace is added for your reference.

Comment: The error is pretty clear. The code though is very hard to read and seems to mix up different classes. Post *only* the DbContext code, including there `OnConfiguring` method

Comment: If this code is configured as an unhandled exception handler, that uses a DbContext to store logs to the database, any errors in that DbContext's method will try to use that DbContext again to log the error. You don't even need an ORM tor logging to a database though, there are no entities involved here, just a database record with specific fields. Most logging frameworks allow logging to a database too. Check eg Serilog and [Serilong.Sinks.MySQL](https://github.com/saleem-mirza/serilog-sinks-mysql)

Comment: You can add extra properties to all logging frameworks. You can configure database sinks to create and write to extra columns, or store arbitrary data to XML or JSON fields.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Thanks for your input. I have modified the code for easy understanding.